# Ubuntu 18.04.4 Wireless is gone completely. Currently on a wired connection

Tags: networking, wireless

Earlier today, I attempted to update my wireless drivers and, now my wireless has completely disappeared. At this point, I am willing to do anything, post any output, just to get it back. Can anyone assist?
Thanks

Result of

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4060]
```

Result of

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
```

```
[16721.465752] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[16721.465753] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8324:9176b151
```

and

result of

```
rfkill list all
```

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
modinfo iwlwifi | grep 088E
```

Returns nothing.

I just ran

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

and this was the output:

```
 *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 10
   serial: 44:8a:5b:40:ae:71
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.1.81 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:19 memory:f7d00000-f7d3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 24
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff
```

Ok, that purge command did nothing.

```
Package 'backport-iwlwifi-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

What started my problem was that, pretty much since updating to 18.04, my wireless has just randomly dropped out and needed to turned off then on again to get it to come back (until it randomly disappeared again...) Yesterday was particularly crazy so, I thought (stupidly apparently,) that if I could just get the latest driver for my wireless adapter, that might fix the random disappearances...

Would it help if I went back through my terminal and compiled a list of commands I ran? Its long...and the longer it gets, the dumber I feel.

Thanks for everything

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: chili555 I updated my question as requested. Though, I don't know if I did it correctly...

Comment: Very fine! Now let's see: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: chili555 Done. Updated as requested.

Comment: Please show us: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 088E`

Comment: "Would it help if I went back through my terminal and compiled a list of commands I ran?" Yes, please. You can get a list in the terminal command: `history`. Copy the ones you feel are relevent and post them here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/x58XXMVrX3/

Comment: Please see my edit in a few moments. You should start a new question so that we may address the instabiity.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks!! I will certainly ask a new question in a day or so to address the instability. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Updated as requested. That command returns nothing.

For reasons that I don't understand, the package that you installed to update your wireless drivers doesn't actually cover your exact and relatively common device. I suspect it is a bug.

Please revert the change you made. If you installed the driver from the Additional Drivers utility, then do:

```
sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

If you installed some other way, from git or compiling from source, please telll us how and we'll further assist.

**EDIT**: Please do:

```
cd backport-iwlwifi/
sudo make uninstall
```

Reboot.

If you installed this driver to overcome another issue, tell us about it and we'll assist.

Comment: See my original question for a small explanation...